# what does BC in "bc from trunk branch" stands for?

Tags: version-control

I just started working at new place in support and in most of the ticket our team works on have "BC from trunk branch" for running a build and deployment. I am not sure what BC stands for in this statement. Can anyone please tell me it stands for?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

**Ask a coworker what it means.** In all likelihood, people will appreciate that you are new there and still learning their lingo. For example, you could even say something like, *"Hi, I'm still learning some of the process around here and was wondering what the 'BC' in 'BC from trunk branch' means?"* You are more likely to get the right answer from someone who works there, rather than the internet.

On the technical side, it sounds like they're using `svn` (from the use of the term "trunk"--`git` uses "master" for the same thing). Judging by the context of the entire phrase, it *may* mean "**Branch Created** from trunk branch", which would more or less be correct terminology in `svn` speak.

Comment: make sense. i will ask requester because most of my teammates doesnt know that either. so i thought this might be something that people here knows.